# Is there any way to append appended message again based on another def in python?

Tags: python

can i know is it possible to append my second loop result to first loop result within 2 def and print only once for similar str? here's the sample of my script, and it is just an simple example i made as my original is complicated.

```
import os

def check(a):
    des = [] 
    
    file_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path2 = "C:\\Users\\Document\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path3 = "C:\\Users\\Picture\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path4 = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + "22-Oct"+ ".txt"
    
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        return file_path
    else:
        des.append("file not exists in downloads.")
    
    if os.path.exists(file_path2):
        return file_path
    else:
        des.append("file not exists in document.")
           
    if os.path.exists(file_path3):
        return file_path
    else:
        des.append("file not exists in picture.")

    if os.path.exists(file_path4):
        return file_path
    else:
        des.append(a + " 22-Oct file not eexists.")
        
    if len(des) != 0:   
        for empty in des:
            print(empty)
                
    elif len(des) == 0:
        print('yes') # going to add another def if true
     
def selected():
    while True:
        a = input('Please select temp or 1456.\n')
        
        if a == "temp" or a == "1456":
            check(a)
        else:
            print("please select again.")

selected()
```

the result im getting is

```
OUTPUT:

Please select temp or 1456.
temp
file not exists in downloads.
file not exists in document.
file not exists in picture.
temp 22-Oct file not exists.

Please select temp or 1456.
1456
file not exists in downloads.
file not exists in document.
file not exists in picture.
1456 22-Oct file not exists.
:
:
```

expected result are the combination of the first and the second then only shows once.

```
Please select temp or 1456.
temp
file not exists in downloads.
file not exists in document.
file not exists in picture.
temp 22-Oct file not exists.

Please select temp or 1456.
1456
file not exists in downloads. ## result from both (shows only once)
file not exists in document.  ## result from both (shows only once)
file not exists in picture.  ## result from both (shows only once)
temp 22-Oct file not exists. ## result from first loop 
1456 22-Oct file not exists. ## result from second loop
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the outputs...

Comment: hi, i edited the expected result thank you.

Comment: Move the `des` list to `selected` and pass it as an argument to `check`? You are initializing `des` with each call to `check`...

Comment: use `append` and `not in`. This might solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the des as a global variable so that it doesn't lose its contents outside the check function.
You also need to check if the message already exists in des before appending to it. Below is a sample from which you can reuse. Note the location of des declaration. We cannot have it within check else it will be initialized each time.

```
def check(a):
    file_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path2 = "C:\\Users\\Document\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path3 = "C:\\Users\\Picture\\" + a + ".txt"
    file_path4 = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\" + a + "22-Oct"+ ".txt"
    
    if "file not exists in downloads." not in des:
        des.append("file not exists in downloads.")
    if "file not exists in downloads." not in des:
        des.append("file not exists in document.")
    if "file not exists in downloads." not in des:
        des.append("file not exists in picture.")
    if (a + " 22-Oct file not exists") not in des:
        des.append(a + " 22-Oct file not exists.")
        
    if len(des) != 0:   
        for empty in des:
            print(empty)
                
    elif len(des) == 0:
        print('yes') # going to add another def if true
     
def selected():
    global des
    des = [] 
    while True:
        a = input('Please select temp or 1456.\n')
        
        if a == "temp" or a == "1456":
            check(a)
        else:
            print("please select again.")

selected()
```